# getElementById() Method not working for my last function

Tags: javascript

I can't get why getElementById() Method not working for my last function. I want that result of this function will apper on the same place where  appearing the results of previouse functions Please help me to get this. If use document.writeln, that works but opens in new window. I can't get the difference.

```js
     function Sum(){
                    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
                    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 + +num2;
                }
                function Difference() {
                    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
                    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 - +num2;
                }
                function Division() {
                    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
                    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 / +num2;
                }
                function Multiplication() {
                    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
                    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 * +num2;
                }
                function testNum() {
                   var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
                   var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
                   document.write ("<CENTER><TABLE BORDER = '1'>") ;
                   if ( num1 == num2) {
                    document.writeln ("<TR><TD>" + num1 +" equal  " + num2 + "</TD></TR>") ;
                   } else if ( num1 != num2) {
                   document.writeln ("<TR><TD>" +num1+ " dosen't equal " +num2+ "</TD></TR>") ;
                   } else if ( num1 < num2) {
                   document.writeln ("<TR><TD>" +num1+ " less than " +num2+ "</TD></TR>") ;
                   } else ( num1 > num2)
                   document.writeln ("<TR><TD>" +num1+ " more than " +num2+ "</TD></TR>") ;
                   document.writeln ("</TABLE></CENTER>") ;
                }
```

```html
<h2>Onderdeel 1</h2>
            <h2>The Sum Program</h2>
            <hr />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Enter A:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" value="3"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Enter B:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" value="4"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="Sum()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="Difference" onClick="Difference()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="Division" onClick="Division()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="Multiplication" onClick="Multiplication()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="testNum" onClick="testNum()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
             <tr>
                    <p>The Result is : <br>
                    <span id = "result"></span>
                    </p>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Don’t use `document.write`, don’t use `document.writeln`. If you want your results at the same place, why not use `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML` as well? But don’t append to it line after line: you can’t append e.g. `<center>` and `</center>` separately.

Comment: Build up a string `result` using concatenation `result += "something"`, and when you're done, call `document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;` just like your other functions. Also, this HTML needs cleanup. Unclosed `<head>` tag that contains the entire document (removed through an edit). Check out https://validator.w3.org/. I recommend [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as well.

Comment: BTW you have and `else` statment with a condition and you don't use brackets in it. An `else` doens't take conditions it literally is everything else that doesn't apply to the other conditions, you should use an `else if` again there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to `document.writein()` method, and it's not opening in a new tab/window. In fact, what is happening is you are writing in the whole document object.
Just open any page and run `document.writeln ("</TABLE></CENTER>")` in console and see the same behaviour.

The solution would be to use `innerHTML`.

Below is the working example:

```js
function Sum() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 + +num2;
}
function Difference() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 - +num2;
}
function Division() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 / +num2;
}
function Multiplication() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 * +num2;
}

function testNum() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  if (num1 == num2) {
    result.innerHTML = num1 + " equal  " + num2;
  } else if (num1 != num2) {
    result.innerHTML = num1 + " not equal  " + num2;
  } else if (num1 < num2) {
    result.innerHTML = num1 + " less than " + num2;
  } else if (num1 > num2) {
    result.innerHTML = num1 + " more than " + num2;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Onderdeel 1</h2>
<h2>The Sum Program</h2>
<hr />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Enter A:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Enter B:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" value="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="Sum()" />
      <input type="button" Value="Difference" onClick="Difference()" />
      <input type="button" Value="Division" onClick="Division()" />
      <input type="button" Value="Multiplication" onClick="Multiplication()" />
      <input type="button" Value="testNum" onClick="testNum()" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<tr>
  <p>The Result is : <br>
    <span id="result"></span>
  </p>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the updated testNum function for your reference

Try your working code - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7FTZOLCXZMR

```
function testNum() {
var num1= parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
var num2= parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
var result = document.getElementById("result"); 
if ( num1 == num2) { 
  result.innerHTML =  num1 +" equal  " + num2 ;
} else if ( num1 != num2) {
  result.innerHTML =  num1 +" not equal  " + num2 ;
} else if ( num1 < num2) { 
  result.innerHTML = num1+ " less than " +num2;
} else if(num1 > num2){ 
  result.innerHTML = num1+ " more than " +num2;
} 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a different approach. Here are my suggestions to help this make this easier:

1. I suggest composing HTML directly instead of dynamically in JavaScript
2. Toggle the table and result using a hide/show function
3. Use a [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for readability

Here is a code snippet as an example:

```js
function Sum(){
    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 + +num2;
    show("result");
}
function Difference() {
    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 - +num2;
    show("result");
}
function Division() {
    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 / +num2;
    show("result");
}
function Multiplication() {
    var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +num1 * +num2;
    show("result");
}
function testNum() {
   var num1= document.getElementById("value1").value;
   var num2= document.getElementById("value2").value;

   var result;
   // using conditional (ternary) operator for readability
   result = num1 === num2 ? num1 + " equal " + num2 : result;
   result = num1 !== num2 ? num1 + " dosen't equal " + num2 : result;
   result = num1 < num2 ? num1 + " less than " + num2 : result;
   result = num1 > num2 ? num1 + " more than " + num2 : result;

   document.getElementById("table-result").innerHTML = result;
   show("table");
}
function show(id) {
   if (id === "table") {
       document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";                           
       document.getElementById("table").style.display = "block";
   } else {
       document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";                          
       document.getElementById("table").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<h2>Onderdeel 1</h2>
            <h2>The Sum Program</h2>
            <hr />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Enter A:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" value="3"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Enter B:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2" value="4"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="Sum()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="Difference" onClick="Difference()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="Division" onClick="Division()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="Multiplication" onClick="Multiplication()" />
                        <input type="button" Value="testNum" onClick="testNum()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
             <tr>
                    <p>The Result is : <br>
                    <span id="result"></span>
                    </p>
                    <table id="table" border="1" style="display:none">
                      <tr>
                        <td><span id="table-result"></span></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </tr>
```